# When comparing benchmarks, is Go or Ruby slower?

Tags: ruby, go

I'm interested in learning Go and have been coding in Ruby for some time now. When comparing benchmarks, which language would be considered faster?

Comment: Languages don't "have speed" - and there are many more productive things to focus on, like which language enables you to most efficiently solve a problem. (Now, Go being a statically-typed compiled language is *clearly* the overhead winner - i.e. it has a much smaller constant factor, close to C#/Java - in implementations which is verified by numerous benchmarks.)

Comment: Everyone's right, but I'd emphasize that you should try the [tour](http://tour.golang.org/), [play around](http://tour.golang.org/), [check out](http://golang.org/ref/spec/) the [various](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) canonical [resources](http://golang.org/pkg/), and see how you like it and how it fits with your work. It can be good for some things without, say, being a drop-in for Rails in terms of its productivity for the particular sort of Web project you might usually work on.

Answer (score 3):

Go is definitely faster. Ruby is getting better, but it has never been fast compared to other popular languages. Here's a breakdown that includes both Go and Ruby: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org

Answer (score 3):

Go is usually much faster than Ruby:

http://blog.iron.io/2013/03/how-we-went-from-30-servers-to-2-go.html

https://plus.google.com/+MattAimonetti/posts/PeZk8FY3PWY

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=go&lang2=yarv&data=u64q